# Arabic words support in lyx IEEE template

Tags: lyx, ieeetran

I need to write some Arabic words in the default lyx template for IEEE transaction. I can write it normally in lyx but when I generate a PDF, I got the following error

[image: Lyx error]

**Edit: Add minimum tex and lyx content**

**Tex content:**

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.2.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[twocolumn,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[LAE,LFE,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[arabic,english]{babel}
\usepackage[unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdftitle={Your Title},
 pdfauthor={Your Name},
 pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% for subfigures/subtables
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Your Title}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Word \textAR{كلمة} 
\end{document}
```

**Lyx content:**

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass IEEEtran
\begin_preamble
% for subfigures/subtables
\usepackage[caption=false,font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\end_preamble
\options journal
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding default
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "default"
\font_sans "default" "default"
\font_typewriter "default" "default"
\font_math "auto" "auto"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\float_placement tbh
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_title "Your Title"
\pdf_author "Your Name"
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered true
\pdf_bookmarksopen true
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder true
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle false
\pdf_quoted_options "pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false"
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 0
\use_package esint 0
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 0
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 0
\use_package stmaryrd 0
\use_package undertilde 0
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 2
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Your Title
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Introduction
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Word
\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none

\family default
\series default
\shape default
\size default
\emph default
\bar default
\strikeout default
\uuline default
\uwave default
\noun default
\color inherit
\lang arabic_arabi
كلمة
\family roman
\series medium
\shape up
\size normal
\emph off
\bar no
\strikeout off
\uuline off
\uwave off
\noun off
\color none
\lang english

\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! That some can help yuo, you need to provide more information in form of small, complete document starting with `\documentclass{...}`, with used packages (essential for your problem),`\begin{document}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In addition to a minimal .tex file, please provide a minimal .lyx file (it is just a text file so you can copy/paste from a text editor). For more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample

Comment: @Zarko I updated the question with the requested tex content.

Comment: @scottkosty both tex and lyx content are added

Comment: I sow your question upgrade :-) . Now lets keep finger crossed that someone familiar to your problem will help you soon. I'm not a such guy :-(.

Answer (score 2):

The following simple document compiles with XeTeX for me on Ubuntu. The main things I changed were:

1. In Document > Settings > Fonts choose "Use non-TeX fonts" and then select fonts that support arabic.
2. In Document > Settings > PDF Properties uncheck "Use hyperref support".
3. I removed your preamble since you didn't mention anything about captions.

Then you can compile with XeTeX or LuaTeX.

.lyx file:

```
#LyX 2.2 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 508
\begin_document
\begin_header
\save_transient_properties true
\origin unavailable
\textclass IEEEtran
\begin_preamble

\end_preamble
\options journal
\use_default_options false
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding default
\fontencoding global
\font_roman "default" "DejaVu Sans"
\font_sans "default" "DejaVu Serif"
\font_typewriter "default" "DejaVu Sans Mono"
\font_math "auto" "default"
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts true
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100 100
\font_tt_scale 100 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\float_placement tbh
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\pdf_title "Your Title"
\pdf_author "Your Name"
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered true
\pdf_bookmarksopen true
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder true
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle false
\pdf_quoted_options "pdfpagelayout=OneColumn, pdfnewwindow=true, pdfstartview=XYZ, plainpages=false"
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine basic
\cite_engine_type default
\biblio_style plain
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 0
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Your Title
\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Introduction
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Word
\lang arabic_arabi
كلمة
\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

.tex file:

```
%% LyX 2.2.1 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Sans}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{DejaVu Serif}
\setmonofont{DejaVu Sans Mono}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\begin{document}

\title{Your Title}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

Word\textarabic{كلمة}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. But unfortunately, disabling hyperref is not an option for me and if I enabled it, I get an error "tex capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size = 5000]". Is there any other solution for this issue?

Comment: @vanilla I'm not sure. If you don't get an answer here, you might want to ask another question that is specifically about hyperref. Consider using the tags "hyperref" and "arabic".